# Complex query, use :includes and :joins at the same time?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

(Using Rails 3.1.3)

I have an app that manages products. I import the products from several resellers and they all name their categories different. Because of this I have resellercategories that are mapped to my own subcategories.

Categories

Subcategories (belongs_to Category)

Resellercategories (belongs_to Subcategory)

Products (belongs_to Resellercategory)

You can see the models and how the relations are defined here:
http://snipt.net/Linuus/category-and-subcategory?key=38ba590408ac4233927a06046eeca30d

On my site I want to display the categories and their subcategories, easy.

If a user filters the products for, say, only 'female' products I want to filter also the categories and subcategories so that only categories and subcategories that have 'female' products are displayed. The gender is stored in the products.

So, how can I do this?

I tried to create a query like this:
http://snipt.net/Linuus/categories-1/?key=2d5d54fd573f0afe60eaa3c47a23fd4d
which (I think) filters the correct Categories. However, when I do something like:

```
@menu_categories.each do |c|
    c.subcategories.each do |sc|
        # do something...
    end
end
```

It still queries all the subcategories whether or not they have female products. So, I got a suggestion over at the Ruby on Rails Google Group to eagerly load the :subcategories using .includes(). So, something like this:

```
Category.includes(:subcategories)
        .joins("INNER JOIN resellercategories AS r ON subcategories.id = r.subcategory_id")
        .joins("INNER JOIN products AS p ON r.id = p.resellercategory_id")
        .group("categories.id")
        .order("categories.name ASC")
        .where("p.gender = 'unisex' OR p.gender = 'female'")
        .where("subcategories.id > 0") # Dummy to trigger eager loading
```

However, when mixing .includes() and .joins() the includes seems to fail to eager load anything. Thus throwing the error below:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: subcategories.id:
SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" 
INNER JOIN resellercategories AS r ON subcategories.id = r.subcategory_id 
INNER JOIN products AS p ON r.id = p.resellercategory_id 
WHERE (p.gender = 'unisex' OR p.gender = 'female') 
GROUP BY categories.id 
ORDER BY categories.name ASC
```

Is this behavior expected? Is it a bug? 
Am I trying to do this the right way or is there a better way to do it?

Any help is very appreciated.

(The discussion on RoR Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/UkCF7jbehHk)

**Solution:**
Ok, so the solution is to use eager_load() instead of includes(). I also had to remove group()
This seems to work for me:

```
 Category.eager_load(:subcategories)
         .joins("INNER JOIN resellercategories AS r ON subcategories.id = r.subcategory_id")
         .joins("INNER JOIN products AS p ON r.id = p.resellercategory_id")
         .order("categories.name ASC")
         .where("p.gender = 'unisex' OR p.gender = 'female'")
```

Comment: The custom `.joins` take precedence or something dumb like that. I'll see if I can think of a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails does not always use joins to realise an include. You can force it too by doing `eager_load` rather than `includes`.

Comment: Thank you! eager_load() seems to do the trick. I also had to remove the group(). Will update the my original post with the correct info.

Answer (score 1):

This AR chain looks a lot cleaner.

```
Category.joins({:subcategories => 
               {:resellercategories =>
                :products}})
         .includes(:subcategories)
         .where('products.gender = unisex OR
                 products.gender = ?', gender)
```

BUT I don't think it will solve your original problem of getting all the `subcategories`. To solve that you'll actually have to query the association.

```
@menu_categories.each do |c|
    c.subcategories.joins({:resellercategories =>
                           :products}})
                   .where('products.gender = unisex OR
                           products.gender = ?', gender)
                   .each do |sc|
        # do something...
    end
end
```